# Wordpress Shortcode displaying data out of order even using return

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I am trying to display some data with my WP Shortcode, but it's showing everything out of order. After searching a bit, the docs say you need to use return in the function, but it's still not working.

Here's the code

```
function dwwp_jobs_from_california($atts){

  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'title' => 'All jobs in California:',
    ),
    $atts
  );

  $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'job'));
  $jobs = "<h1>" . $atts['title'] . '</h1><br>';
  if( $query->have_posts()):
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
      $query->the_post();
      $jobs .= '<h3>' . the_title() . '</h3><br>';
    endwhile;
  endif;

  $jobs .= "End of the loop!";
  wp_reset_query();
  return $jobs;
  }

add_shortcode('jobs_california', 'dwwp_jobs_from_california');
```

**In my Wordpress page:**

```
"Content of the page"

[jobs_california]
```

**What it is rendering on the page:**

```
[jobs_california]
"Content of the page"
```

I must also admit i'm not very used to work with PHP, so sorry if my code quality is not nice.

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! So when you say "out of order", what do you mean? What order are they in, and what order do you expect?

Comment: Sorry, my problem is a "common problem" with shortcodes, where the Shortcode is displayed before the page content. I will edit the question :)

Comment: But people often have this problem when they use echo instead of return to the function, but that's not the point here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only problem you are having is that you are using `the_title()` which will `echo` the post title... But you want to build a html string instead, that will be returned by your short code function. Try using:

```
the_title('', '', false)
```

or, much better:

```
get_the_title()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what was happening! Fixed with get_the_title()